# Convert a (txt|srt) document from Western(ISO-8859-15) to UTF-8

Tags: gedit, encoding, utf-8

I  am having problems with subtitles in my language. They are encoded as *Western(ISO-8859-15)* and therefore some characters are not displayed correctly. I am tired of replacing manually using gedit and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> and then saving as UTF-8. How to automate this process?

Comment: The process using `iconv` will most likely work flawlessly if you are not using characters outside the English latin set. If you encounter any problems, check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/277580/58950

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv):

If the file is named `chapter1.srt`, then run:

```
iconv -f iso88591 -t utf8 chapter1.srt > outputfile.srt
```

and it will create the file, although it'll have a different name. If you move them out into another directory, then you can easily pipe them back in.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

## [konwert](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/konwert) [image: Install konwert]

```
konwert isolatin1-utf8 inputfile.srt > outputfile.srt
```

Besides conversion, `konwert` can also be used as an encoding *detector*:

```
konwert any/en-test inputfile.srt
```

Which is great to get the input file encoding needed for the conversion, since both `konwert` and `iconv` requires that as argument. You must however provide a language parameter: `en` in `any/en-test` means English

It also has an option for in-place conversion, so you don't have to move and rename files afterwards:

```
konwert isolatin1-utf8 -O inputfile.srt
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, since you're dealing with `.srt` files, you should really check [pysrt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysrt). It has many features to manipulate subtitles, like shifting and rescaling times.

Installing:

```
sudo pip install pysrt
```

Converting to UTF-8 (it auto-detects input file encoding using either `chardet` or `charade`)

```
srt -i --encoding 'utf-8' shift 0s mysubtitle.srt
```